# Interface with generic object of the interface type

Tags: c#, .net, interface

I have the following interface:

```
public interface IObject
{
    double x { get; }
    double y { get; }
    Holder<IObject> Holder { get; set; }
}
```

and this class

```
public class Holder<T> where T : IObject 
{
  private List<T> items; 
  public void AddItem(T item){
     items.Add(item);
     item.Holder = this;
}
```

However the compiler doesn't like the AddItem method and on this line :

```
item.Holder = this;
```

gives me this error:

```
Cannot convert source type 'Holder<T>' to target type 'Holder<IObject>'
```

Why can't I do it and what is a good solution for this scenario?
thank you

Comment: Why not use public class Holder<IObject>?

Comment: Why have you asked the same question twice?

Comment: it's not same question, i had too many mistakes on the previous question so i wrote a new one. and also this is a different case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to bear in mind the way Genrics works in C#, The compiler create a class of the specified type, and because of that you have the error.

To explain more, given the following example:

```
public class InterfaceImplementation : IObject
{
}
```

and then some where you do :

```
var genericInitialisation = new Holder<InterfaceImplementation>();
```

The compiler at compile time will create a class `HolderInterfaceImplementation` replacing all accurances of the `T` generic parameter.

so after compilation you will have this class:

```
public class HolderInterfaceImplementation
{
  private ListInterfaceImplementation items; 
  public void AddItem(InterfaceImplementation item){
     items.Add(item);
     item.Holder = this;
}
```

And `item.Holder` would be `HolderIObject` type, so the compiler report an error about not being able to convert `HolderInterfaceImplementation` to `HolderIObject` wich is logical.

After explaining the theory the solution comes naturaly and here is an example:

```
    public interface IObject<T> where T : IObject<T>
    {
      double x { get; }
      double y { get; }
      Holder<T> Holder { get; set; }
    }


    public class Holder<T> where T : IObject<T>
    {
      public Holder()
      {
        items = new List<T>();
      }
      private List<T> items;
      public void AddItem(T item)
      {
        items.Add(item);
        item.Holder = this;
      }
    }

    public class Implementation : IObject<Implementation>
    {

      public double x
      {
        get { return 0; }
      }

      public double y
      {
        get { return 0; }
      }

      public Holder<Implementation> Holder
      {
        get;
        set;
      }
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      var t = new Holder<Implementation>();
      t.AddItem(new Implementation());
      Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: awesome and detailed answer, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If it was possible to convert that would be a type system hole:

```
public class Holder<T> where T : IObject 
{
  public T SomeField;
}
...
var holder = new Holder<IObjectSubType2>();
Holder<IObject> dummy = holder; //assuming that this works
dummy.SomeField = new IObjectSubType1(); //violates type safety
IObjectSubType2 converted = holder.SomeField;
```

As you can see I was able to convert an instance of `IObjectSubType1` to an `IObjectSubType2`.

That's why this does not type check.