# Why I cannot cast an object to an interface it is implementing?

Tags: c#, generics, collections, interface, variance

I have 2 public interfaces used by a client

```
public interface IASet<T> where T : IItem {
    HashSet<T> Collection { get; set; }
}

public interface IItem {
    string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The idea is for the client to access the data through this object :

```
IASet<IItem> aset = GetIt();
foreach(IItem i in aset.Collection)
    Console.WriteLine(i.Name);
```

The concrete implementation is as follow :

```
private class ASet : IASet<OneItem>{
    public HashSet<OneItem> Collection { get; set; }
}
private class OneItem : IItem{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And finnaly the function generating the objects :

```
public static IASet<IItem> GetIt()
{
    ASet a = new ASet();
    a.Collection = new HashSet<OneItem>();
    a.Collection.Add(new OneItem() { Name = "one" });
    a.Collection.Add(new OneItem() { Name = "two" });
    //for test :
    foreach (IItem i in a.Collection)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i.Name);
    }

    /*Error 1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'ConsoleApplication2.Program.ASet'
     * to 'ConsoleApplication2.IASet<ConsoleApplication2.IItem>'. An explicit
     * conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
    */
    //return a;


    /*Unable to cast object of type 'ASet' to type
     * 'ConsoleApplication2.IASet`1[ConsoleApplication2.IItem]'.
     */
    return (IASet<IItem>)a;
}
```

Because my real code is not as simple as this one, I cannot change `ASet : IASet<OneItem>` to something like `ASet<T> : IASet<T>`

Could you please explain me why I cannot do that, and some suggestions to correct the problem ?

Thanks

Comment: Because `T` on IASet is invariant. It it were declared like so, `IASet<out T>`, it would work - but you can't do that because HashSet won't accept it.

Comment: I believe this would work only if the `IASet`'s generic type is defined as an `out` template parameter. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469487.aspx There's nothing preventing someone from adding a different class of `IItem` objects to the collection in the set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should take a look at my response to this question, it explains you case [Interface with generic object of the interface type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19514499/interface-with-generic-object-of-the-interface-type/19514978#19514978)

By the way I suggest you make changes to you GetIt Function like that :

```
public static IASet<T> GetIt<T>() 
  where T : IItem
{
  ASet a = new ASet();
  a.Collection = new HashSet<OneItem>();
  a.Collection.Add(new OneItem() { Name = "one" });
  a.Collection.Add(new OneItem() { Name = "two" });
  //for test :
  foreach (var i in a.Collection)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(i.Name);
  }

  /*Error 1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'ConsoleApplication2.Program.ASet'
   * to 'ConsoleApplication2.IASet<ConsoleApplication2.IItem>'. An explicit
   * conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
  */
  //return a;


  /*Unable to cast object of type 'ASet' to type
   * 'ConsoleApplication2.IASet`1[ConsoleApplication2.IItem]'.
   */
  return (IASet<T>)a;
}
```

and then you need to call it like that:

```
  IASet<OneItem> aset = GetIt<OneItem>();
  foreach (IItem i in aset.Collection)
    Console.WriteLine(i.Name);
```

if you want more details you have to explain your requirement more.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is you are returning an instance of `ASet` but the return type is `IASet<IItem>`.  The `ASet` type actually implements the interface `IASet<OneItem>`.  This interface is not convertible to `IASet<IItem>` even though `OneItem` implements `IITem`.

This type of conversion is allowed when the type parameter on `IASet` is marked with `out` (i.e. `IASet<out T>`).  This would identify the type parameter as covariant and allow for this type of conversion.

Unfortunately this is not possible in your scenario.  The easiest way to think of `out T` is that `T` only appears in output positions on the API.  In this case `T` is used in `HashSet<T>`.  In that usage `T` appears in both input and output positions hence `T` can't be marked as `out`.